# Who knows, or knows how to figure out, which google map markers are available?

Tags: google-maps, colors, google-maps-markers, rgb

I want to use a variety of location markers in a map, of different colors. I like google's "teardrop"-shaped ones so that the location itself is less obscured, due to the point top of the inverted teardrop.

This is a link to the green one:

```
http://www.googlemapsmarkers.com/v1/009900/
```

...and the green uses 0099FF

But what about the other colors? Is there a list somewhere or do I have to write a utility to convert color to RGB, or what?

Even with that, how would I know which colors are supported/supplied? Or are the colors dynamically generated based on the RGB value you pass?

### UPDATE

Based on the chart here:

http://cloford.com/resources/colours/500col.htm

...I would expect that entering this:

http://www.googlemapsmarkers.com/v1/65535/

...would return a bright yellow marker, but instead I get:

"***400. That’s an error.
Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request.
The parameter 'chs' must have a width of at least 1 pixel.
That’s all we know.***"

### UPDATE 2

I also found that you can put text on the marker by inserting the text in the penultimate spot.

This returns a blank yellow inverted teardrop:

```
http://www.googlemapsmarkers.com/v1/FFFF00/
```

..and this:

```
http://www.googlemapsmarkers.com/v1/Platypus/FFFF00/
```

...returns an inverted yellow teardrop with the word "Platypus" plastered on top of it.

Comment: Did you see the [description of the site](http://www.googlemapsmarkers.com/) or the [description of how it works](http://www.googlemapsmarkers.com/how-it-works.html), uses the [Google Charts API](http://chart.apis.google.com) under the covers.

Comment: Based on that chart, I would expect this hex code to give a bright yellow marker: #FFFF00.  [link](http://www.googlemapsmarkers.com/v1/FFFF00/)

Comment: Yes, if I remove the pound/hash sign, it does. So is there some chart somewhere that shows FFF00 == yellow, etc.?

Comment: The [one you linked to](http://cloford.com/resources/colours/500col.htm) does. `yellow 1 (yellow*)   yellow 1 (yellow*) #FFFF00 255 255 0 65535` (but there should be four F's not three).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass your own RGB color. I suppose the markers are dynamically generated when the server receive your request, but anyway, you can create the color you exactly want.